# Занесение в базу данных phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток. Для обучения работы с selenium мне понадобилась форма регистрации, заносящая данные в БД.
Для этих целей был ̶п̶о̶з̶а̶и̶м̶с̶т̶в̶о̶в̶а̶н̶ нагло спижжен следующий код:

Своими усилиями, к сожалению, заставить его работать я не смог. Возможно кто-то подскажет как это реализовать?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function sanitize_input(&$request) {
    $request = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($request));
}

if ($_POST["submit"]) {
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'sanitize_input');

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
mysql_select_db("test",$db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (first,last,address,position) VALUES ('".$_POST["first"]."','".$_POST["last"]."','".$_POST["address"]."','"._POST["$position"]."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "Thank you! Information entered.\n";
} else {
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
First name:<input type="Text" name="first"><br>
Last name:<input type="Text" name="last"><br>
Address:<input type="Text" name="address"><br>
Position:<input type="Text" name="position"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

P.s. 
Название БД - test
Таблицы - people
Полей - first,last,address и position соответственно.
База данных - phpMyAdmin
Для доступа используется WampServer

Answer (score 0):

В форме поменяйте это:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

На это:

```
<form method="post" action="PAGENAME.php">
```

Где PAGENAME - название вашей страницы например - index.php

Comment: С php я знаком всего час. Конечно, когда-то я приду к пониманию всего этого. Но сейчас...
Воспользовался Вашим примером. Данные в таблицу занесены не были.
Нужны ли еще какие-то ресурсы? Или может быть дополнительная информация?

Comment: Так каков результат?

Comment: Пароль для входа не требуется

Comment: @PavelBobrov, выведите проверку соединения с базой.

Comment: Добавьте в код то, что я написал выше

Comment: Прошу прощения. Уже пробовал вариант с or die. Он как и Ваш не принес никаких результатов. При нажатии кнопки просто пытается переместить на непонятную страницу - file:///C:/Users/users/Desktop/<?php%20echo%20$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]?>

Comment: А, тьфу. Только сейчас заметил))

Название у вашей страницы какое и зачем вам получать ссылку на файл обработчик если можно просто указать его ссылкой?))

Comment: @PavelBobrov обновил ответ.